# Apache-Spark UDF defined inside object raises "No TypeTag available for String"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I get different behaviors for copy pasting a function during an interactive session versus compiled with sbt.

[*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the interactive session:

```
$ sbt package 
[error] src/main/scala/xxyy.scala:6: No TypeTag available for String
[error]     val correctDiacritics = udf((s: scala.Predef.String) => {
[error]                                ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed May 22, 2018 2:22:52 PM
$ cat src/main/scala/xxyy.scala 
package xxx.yyy
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
object DummyObject {
    val correctDiacritics = udf((s: scala.Predef.String) => {
            s.replaceAll("è","e")
            .replaceAll("é","e")
            .replaceAll("à","a")
            .replaceAll("ç","c")
            })
}
```

The aforementioned code does not compile. However during an interactive session:

```
// During the `spark-shell` session.
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
object DummyObject {
val correctDiacritics = udf((s: scala.Predef.String) => {
    s.replaceAll("è","e")
    .replaceAll("é","e")
    .replaceAll("à","a")
    .replaceAll("ç","c")
})
}
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
// import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
// defined object DummyObject
// Proceeds sucessfully.
```

---

Versions:

- I'm using `Scala 2.11`.
- I'm using `Spark 2.1.0`.
- `built.sbt`:

  ```
  name := "my_app"

  version := "0.0.1"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

  resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver sonatypeRepo "public",
  Resolver typesafeRepo "releases"
  )
  resolvers += "MavenRepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com/"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  // "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
  //"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.2",
  // "org.apache.spark" %
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.1.0"
  )
  ```

---

Related questions:

- [udf No TypeTag available for type string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173067/udf-no-typetag-available-for-type-string).

  - Accepted answer does not solve the problem.
- [Spark, sbt package -- No TypeTag available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761672/spark-sbt-package-no-typetag-available).

  - No answer as of 2018-05-22.
- [No typeTag available Error in scala spark udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520033/no-typetag-available-error-in-scala-spark-udf).

  - No answer as of 2018-05-22.
- [Spark UDF error no TypeTag available for string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207742/spark-udf-error-no-typetag-available-for-string).

  - No answer as of 2018-05-22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build definition is incorrect:

- You build your project with Scala 2.11.12
- But use Spark dependencies build with Scala 2.10

As Scala is not binary compatible between major version, you get an error.

Instead embedding Scala version it is better to use `%%`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0"
)
```

otherwise make sure you use the right build:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.0"
)
```